# Что делать дальше с объектом Closure?

Tags: ооп, php, замыкания

Только начал разбираться с замыканиями/анонимными функциями. Есть вопрос на фундаментальном уровне. Вот простейший пример:

```
function func1(){
    return function (){
        return 1;
    };
}
```

...и как это использовать? Первое, что приходит мне в голову - `func1()` возвращает то, что возвращает анонимная функция. Однако если я напишу 
`echo func1()`;

я получаю ошибку:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in [file_name] on line 29
```

Максимум, что я пока что могу получить, это объект Closure:

```
var_dump(func1());
---------------------
object(Closure)[1]
```

Но практического применения этого не вижу никакого, т.к. у меня этот объект ВСЕГДА содержит одно и то же, независимо от того, что возвращает анонимная функция:

```
object(Closure)[1]
```

использую (php 5.3.3)
Кроме того, непонятно, как сохранить возвращаемое анонимной функцией значение внутри `func1()`; Насколько я понимаю, она всегда возвращает объект `Closure`. Но как с ним работать дальше?

Comment: Хммм `func1()()` ?

Comment: Ретируюсь. Я уже был готов перейти на пхп 5.3 и таки порадоваться новым замыканиям, но вот потестил на wamp'е... 

Смех и грех блин, бараны изменили, по сути, синтаксис `create_function` и объявили это полноценным замыканием.

Хотя в более вменяемом JS можно делать, например, так

    (function() { console.log(myFunc().a()()().get(5).exec(function() { return 2; })); })();

В общем, @thunder ответил более-менее правильно, хоть это и каммент с php.net =) От себя скажу, что когда аффтары пхп что-то сделают вменяемо - надо будет готовиться к аномалиям.

Comment: да, это коммент именно оттуда, зачастую они вносят бОльший смысл в описание функции :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have been disapointed if you tried to call a closure stored in an instance variable as you would regularly do with methods:

```
<?php
$obj = new StdClass();
$obj->func = function(){
 echo "hello";
};
//$obj->func(); // doesn't work! php tries to match an instance method called "func" that is not defined in the original class' signature
// you have to do this instead:
$func = $obj->func;
$func();

// or:
call_user_func($obj->func);
// however, you might wanna check this out:
$array['func'] = function(){
 echo "hello";
};
$array['func'](); // it works! i discovered that just recently ;)
?>
```

Comment: Thanx but I can't see yet how can I use it exactly in my case. Can you show it in MY example?

Comment: @srgg67, I can :)

    $f = func1();
    echo $f();

Comment: Работает! Оформите как ответ плз. - зафиксирую.

Comment: @srgg67 ответ дал thunder.

Comment: Мне ответ @thunder непонятен. Ответ @Sh4dow понятен. Если он вам кажется слишком простым, то, во-первых, он отвечает именно на мой вопрос, а во-вторых, вот отличный, более подробный ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132483/php-closure-what-to-do-next-with-it/18134487?noredirect=1#18134487